# zend two forms same page are submitted together

Tags: php, zend-framework, form-submit

I built two custom Zend_Form classes: form_1 and form_2.I instanciated both of them in the same controller.

```
$form_1=new form_1();
$form_2=new form_2();
```

form_1 and form_2 have respectively submit buttons named 'submit_form_1' the first and 'submit_form_2' the second. (Ex. new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit_form_1')..)

So I added to my controller a snippet to check wich form was submitted :

```
if(($this->_request->isPost('submit_form_1')))
{
 echo "you clicked for form_1!";
}

if($this->_request->isPost('submit_form_2'))
{
 echo "you clicked for form_2!";
}
```

But it seems that clicking on either submit_form_1 or submit_form_2 both of my forms are posted! so that the above snippet output is:

```
you clicked for form_1!you clicked for form_2!
```

what am I missing?

P.s. Both of the form action are left blank so that the form post to same page(I'd prefer to not address these two forms to different actions as you might suggest =))

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Zend_Controller_Request_Http::isPost()` does not take (or use) any arguments.

Both of your conditions are evaluating to true because the request method is POST.

I think you want to use `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getPost()` instead, eg

```
if ($this->_request->getPost('submit_form_1', false)) {
    echo "you clicked for form_1!";
}

if ($this->_request->getPost('submit_form_2', false)) {
    echo "you clicked for form_2!";
}
```